# Does a superconducting state change in a Type 2 collapse the whole superconductor?

Tags: superconductivity

If (say) we have a 1m length bar of a Type 2 superconductor in a superconducting state and something is done to one end of it to collapse the superconduction there, does the state of the whole bar change?

Comment: No... why should it change ? If you heat locally the bar, it becomes non-superconducting again, but why the remaining part of the bar which is below the critical temperature would change its state ? Of course if you continue heating at some point the entire bar will reach a thermodynamics equilibrium and the superconductivity will be destroyed entirely. Things are more tricky for smaller systems, though. The problem has nothing to do with the type of the superconductor (type I, intermediate state, type II in the vortex state or not, high-Tc, ...) nor with the specific compounds.

Comment: I was wondering because it is supposed to be an example of a macroscopic quantum system.

Comment: I understand that the notion of phase rigidity is indeed troublesome. But actually what you do to break the superconducting state is to weaken this phase rigidity. So, droplet of the superconductivity can nucleate when you lower the temperature from above the critical one, and vice versa if you increase the temperature from below, the superconductor tends to become less and less a macroscopic piece of coherent/quantum system.